# Decrypting the Connection String in App.config

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application in which I have some connection strings which are encrypted as shown below:

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
          </KeyInfo>
          <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>soemvalue here</CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>some valye here</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </connectionStrings>
```

I try to access the connection string using the console application like this:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

I get the following error:

> Failed to decrypt using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: The RSA key container could not be opened.

When I try to access the same connection string from app.config without decryption then it works fine. Is there any problem with the encryption? I thought that after encryption I just have to fetch the connection string in normal manner and it will decrypt automatically.

Comment: are you running on the same machine where you encrypted this settings?

Comment: Dumb question - is it being encrypted on one machine, and you're trying to read it on another?  Because it has to be encrypted on the same machine or it won't work.

Comment: this is in no way a "dumb question"

Comment: Actually it was encrypted in a different machine and I am decrypting on a separate machine. If you can post the answer I can accept it! Not a dumb question!

Comment: @dumdum - go ahead. You beat me in the comment.  You'll get my vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encrypt and decrypt on the same machine, or you need to export / import the key.

See this article:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/d43a4bd7-7cc1-40cf-8269-82c92894df43/